# How to combine two completely different SQL queries into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new with SQL queries and could use some help.

I have two different SQL queries and I want the results of both in one result.

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    MAX(orkrg.refer) AS oms25, 
    MAX(gbkmut.docnumber) AS YourRef, 
    MIN(gbkmut.datum) AS datum, 
    cicmpy.debcode AS delv_debnr, 
    MAX(cicmpy.cmp_name) AS cmp_name,
    MAX(gbkmut.datum) AS latest_deldat, 
FROM 
    gbkmut 
INNER JOIN 
    orkrg ON gbkmut.bkstnr_sub = orkrg.ordernr
INNER JOIN
    cicmpy ON orkrg.verzdebnr  = cicmpy.debnr
INNER JOIN 
    items ON gbkmut.artcode = items.itemcode AND items.type <> 'P'
INNER JOIN 
    magaz ON gbkmut.warehouse = magaz.magcode AND magaz.blokkeer = 0 
WHERE 
    (gbkmut.transsubtype IN ('B','H')
     AND gbkmut.freefield1 = 'V'
     AND gbkmut.Blockitem = 0
     AND gbkmut.afldat <= GETDATE()) 
    AND gbkmut.Checked = 1 
    AND (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 0 OR (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 1 AND orkrg.ordbv_afgd = 1)) 
GROUP BY 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    gbkmut.afldat, 
    cicmpy.debcode
ORDER BY 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [Debtor code],
    [Outstanding Amount]
FROM 
    [456].[dbo].[GRV_DebtorOutstanding]
```

[Debtor code] and cicmpy.debcode are the same for a join

Some example results from both queries:

Query 1 columns:

```
Ordernumber, Order description, Your reference, Orderdate, Debtor code, Debtor name, Order delivery date

   20093    NULL    Bestel.: 20093  2018-07-31 00:00:00.000                60089    Restaurant Enkhuizen    2018-07-31 00:00:00.000
   20092    NULL    Bestel.: 20092  2018-07-31 00:00:00.000                60089    Restaurant Enkhuizen    2018-07-31 00:00:00.000
   20088    NULL    Bestel.: 20088  2018-07-05 00:00:00.000                60105    Brasserie Pigalle   2018-07-05 00:00:00.000
```

Query 2:

Columns: Debtor code, Total outstanding amount

```
Debtor code Outstanding Amount
               60086    -30,65
               60092    -121
               60089    -5000
               60130    1000
```

I would like to add the total outstanding amount to the first query.

I tried with a subselect but I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And a union would probably be out of the question as well because of the different columns.

I would like to use this for reporting purposes and could of course solve it via Excel and vlookup, but I would like to do it in SQL to learn more about SQL.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you can use `VLOOKUP` then you could just put results into temp tables and do a left join most likely:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please post the attempt to use a subquery so that we can tell you why you got the error you got.

Comment: you could make the second query a sub-query, then join to it - how do the two queries join though?  How do you know which row in 1 to add a debt from 2 to?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574442/inner-join-vs-inner-join-select-from

Answer (score 2):

Put them both in subqueries and join them together

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    MAX(orkrg.refer) AS oms25, 
    MAX(gbkmut.docnumber) AS YourRef, 
    MIN(gbkmut.datum) AS datum, 
    cicmpy.debcode AS delv_debnr, 
    MAX(cicmpy.cmp_name) AS cmp_name,
    MAX(gbkmut.datum) AS latest_deldat, 
FROM 
    gbkmut 
INNER JOIN 
    orkrg ON gbkmut.bkstnr_sub = orkrg.ordernr
INNER JOIN
    cicmpy ON orkrg.verzdebnr  = cicmpy.debnr
INNER JOIN 
    items ON gbkmut.artcode = items.itemcode AND items.type <> 'P'
INNER JOIN 
    magaz ON gbkmut.warehouse = magaz.magcode AND magaz.blokkeer = 0 
WHERE 
    (gbkmut.transsubtype IN ('B','H')
     AND gbkmut.freefield1 = 'V'
     AND gbkmut.Blockitem = 0
     AND gbkmut.afldat <= GETDATE()) 
    AND gbkmut.Checked = 1 
    AND (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 0 OR (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 1 AND orkrg.ordbv_afgd = 1)) 
GROUP BY 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    gbkmut.afldat, 
    cicmpy.debcode
ORDER BY 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub DESC
) T1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 
        [Debtor code],
        [Outstanding Amount]
    FROM 
        [456].[dbo].[GRV_DebtorOutstanding]
) T2 ON T2.[Debtor code] = T1.delv_debnr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making your second query a common table expression:

```
WITH agg
AS (SELECT TOP 1000
           [Debtor code]
         , [Outstanding Amount]
    FROM [456].[dbo].[GRV_DebtorOutstanding])
SELECT gbkmut.bkstnr_sub
     , MAX(orkrg.refer) AS oms25
     , MAX(gbkmut.docnumber) AS YourRef
     , MIN(gbkmut.datum) AS datum
     , cicmpy.debcode AS delv_debnr
     , MAX(cicmpy.cmp_name) AS cmp_name
     , MAX(gbkmut.datum) AS latest_deldat
     , ISNULL(agg.[Outstanding Amount],0) AS [Outstanding Amount]
FROM gbkmut
    INNER JOIN orkrg ON gbkmut.bkstnr_sub = orkrg.ordernr
    INNER JOIN cicmpy ON orkrg.verzdebnr = cicmpy.debnr
    INNER JOIN items ON gbkmut.artcode = items.itemcode
                        AND items.type <> 'P'
    INNER JOIN magaz ON gbkmut.warehouse = magaz.magcode
                        AND magaz.blokkeer = 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN agg ON agg.[Debtor code] = cicmpy.debcode
WHERE (
          gbkmut.transsubtype IN ( 'B', 'H' )
          AND gbkmut.freefield1 = 'V'
          AND gbkmut.Blockitem = 0
          AND gbkmut.afldat <= GETDATE()
      )
      AND gbkmut.Checked = 1
      AND
      (
          orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 0
          OR
          (
              orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 1
              AND orkrg.ordbv_afgd = 1
          )
      )
GROUP BY gbkmut.bkstnr_sub
       , gbkmut.afldat
       , cicmpy.debcode
       , agg.[Outstanding Amount]
ORDER BY gbkmut.bkstnr_sub DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select * from (


    SELECT 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    MAX(orkrg.refer) AS oms25, 
    MAX(gbkmut.docnumber) AS YourRef, 
    MIN(gbkmut.datum) AS datum, 
    cicmpy.debcode AS delv_debnr, 
    MAX(cicmpy.cmp_name) AS cmp_name,
    MAX(gbkmut.datum) AS latest_deldat, 
FROM 
    gbkmut 
INNER JOIN 
    orkrg ON gbkmut.bkstnr_sub = orkrg.ordernr
INNER JOIN
    cicmpy ON orkrg.verzdebnr  = cicmpy.debnr
INNER JOIN 
    items ON gbkmut.artcode = items.itemcode AND items.type <> 'P'
INNER JOIN 
    magaz ON gbkmut.warehouse = magaz.magcode AND magaz.blokkeer = 0 
WHERE 
    (gbkmut.transsubtype IN ('B','H')
     AND gbkmut.freefield1 = 'V'
     AND gbkmut.Blockitem = 0
     AND gbkmut.afldat <= GETDATE()) 
    AND gbkmut.Checked = 1 
    AND (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 0 OR (orkrg.ordbv_afdr = 1 AND orkrg.ordbv_afgd = 1)) 
GROUP BY 
    gbkmut.bkstnr_sub, 
    gbkmut.afldat, 
    cicmpy.debcode


    Union all

    SELECT TOP 1000 
    bkstnr_sub as '',
    oms25 as 0,
    YourRef as 0, 
    datum as 0,
    delv_debnr as 0, 
    cmp_name as ''
    [Debtor code],
    latest_deldat as NULL
    [Outstanding Amount]
FROM 
    [456].[dbo].[GRV_DebtorOutstanding]
 ) as outertable
```

Comment: You can do it by column alias name same as first query. I have put it into a sub select so you can also do your other operation using outer select.